# Adding Homepage/Splashscreen to PhotoEditorSDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, homescreen, photoeditorsdk

How do I add a home activity or splash screen before PhotoEditor SDK launches in Android Studio?

The application launches immediately due to:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PESDK.init(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: For splash screen i create a separate Activity and load it for 1 or 2 seconds then intent to next activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the PhotoEditorSDK, the PESDK.init() methode only initialize the SDK (this took less than 1ms)

Please look here for an example:
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/